# How to write meaningful test case title in TestNG+Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-automation-framework, testng

When writing manual test cases, the test case title used to be something like

> TC1: Verify that the user is able to login to facebook and react using
>   heart.

When trying to automate the scenario using selenium+ TestNG, how to write meaningful test case titles.

**Note:** I believe that in TestNG, the test case name is the same as the method identifier under @test annotation

```
//Testcase 1
  @Test
  public void VerifyThatUserCanLoginToFaceebookAndReactUsingHeart() {
   //Writeyourcodehere
}
```

Is it permissible to write such long method names or is there a better way to write test case names in TestNG or/and selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the method name simple and add description in the `@Test` annotation like this:

```
@Test(description = "User can log into facebook and react with heart")
public void loginReactHeart() {
    //some code 
}
```

Comment: is there any other way? or this is the recommended practice. Here the description is not coming in emailable report

Comment: You will have to customize the report to include description

Answer (score 0):

Every software testing company has its own practice to follow in automation frameworks.

The way mentioned in your query is also correct but to avoid long method names user can pick the important keywords from the test case which can easily tell the purpose of the method without reading the internal code written inside the method.

For example:

//Testcase 1
  @Test
  public void VerifyFacebookLoginWithReactUsingHeart() {
   //Writeyourcodehere
}

Moreover, proper naming convention should be followed like words should be in camel case notation.